# Mustache.to_html, result to be sorted?

Tags: jquery, mustache, templating

I get results from a Mustache.to_html-call, but the results (displayed in a table) are sorted a wrong way. Is there a way to change that?

```
var result = Mustache.to_html(template, response);
$("#resultTable").html(result);
```

---

More "detailed":

```
function GetDataFirst() {
    var sCustomerNo = $("#tbCustomerNo").val();
    var url = "/Credit/GetData?customerno=" + sCustomerNo;
    GetJson(url, SetDataComplete);
}

function SetDataComplete(response) {
    var tpl = $("#CustomerData").html();
    var result = Mustache.to_html(tpl, response);
    $("#resultTable").html(result);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: see above; I've edited my initial question. Hope that helps..